# Can seccomp be used to enforce deterministic execution?

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel

`seccomp(2)` can be used to severely limit what syscalls can be made from a particular process, including syscalls that introduce non-determinism such as `getrandom(2)` and `gettimeofday(2)`. Is there a way to force the process's execution to be **entirely** deterministic?

At a minimum, I'm guessing that I would need to prevent the process from using `RDTSC`. I found [this old blog post](http://blog.cr0.org/2009/05/time-stamp-counter-disabling-oddities.html) describing how `prctl(PR_SET_TSC)` is actually broken on x86_64. Is there a modern way to work around this problem, or is it impossible to enforce perfectly deterministic execution?

Answer (score 1):

Non-determinism has many sources, not just RDTSC. For one thing, if a program is multi-threaded, it will be able to pick up entropy from scheduling decisions, especially on an SMP system. If we're talking single-threaded programs with severely limited IPC, it may be that a restrictive seccomp jail would do the trick.

You can always patch the kernel to fix the RDTSC flaw. As mentioned by @Gilles, you may need to disable ASLR as well.

Comment: You'd need more than a seccomp jail to get determinism. For example, with ALSR, `mmap` includes a random number generator.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't require users to install a custom kernel.

Comment: Single-threading is fine. In fact, the original seccomp restrictions (just read, write, sigreturn, exit) are acceptable as well.

Comment: @TimMcLean I haven't looked into this, but is there a chance it can work if you use a legacy 32-bit binary on an x86_64 host? Does `prctl` work then?